# Golang GORM "Has Many"

Tags: golang, gorm

В следующем коде одному пользователю может принадлежать большое количество структур типа Pair{}, но при по пытке реализовать следующий код выходит ошибка: "повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает
ограничение уникальности "users_pkey".

```go
type User struct {
    Id uint `json:"id"`
    Email string       `json:"email" gorm:"unique_index"`
    Password []byte    `json:"-"`
    Pairs []Pair        `gorm:"foreignKey:Symbol" json:"pairs"`
}

type Pair struct {
    Symbol string `json:"symbol"`
    Volume int64  `json:"volume"`
}

database.Connect()
database.AutoMigrate(models.User{}, models.Pair{})
```

А в другом скрипте выполняю следующий код:

```go
database.Connect()

    for i := 0; i < 40; i++{
        var orderItems []models.Pair

        for j := 0; j < rand.Intn(5); j++ {
            orderItems = append(orderItems, models.Pair {
                Symbol: faker.Word(),
                Volume: int64(rand.Intn((800) + 1)),
            })
        }

        database.DB.Create(&models.User{
            Id: uint(rand.Intn((2000) + 1)),
            Email: faker.Email(),
            Password: []byte(faker.Password()),
            Pairs:   orderItems,
        }),
    }
```

Comment: ```Id: uint(rand.Intn((2000) + 1)),``` вы и правда считаете это **УНИКАЛЬНЫМ** значением?

Comment: Не нужно менять код на картинки, читаемость снижается, и вам врятли кто либо поможет.(в чем ошибка - написано еще в первом комментарии :)

Comment: По поводу Id: для группы из пяти orderItems он будет уникальным с большой долей вероятности. 
По поводу картинок: спасибо за совет, я не знал, думал наоборот :)

Comment: Ну т.е. сообщение об ошибке вы даже не пытались перевести? а оно говорит вам что primary(главный) ключ нарушает ограничение уникальности, в вашем случае это id, и random не гарантирующий никакой уникальности даже в рамках **двух** значений подряд - вы не свели воедино?) (p.s. и да бывает так что random выдает повторяющиеся значения даже подряд) а у вас я не вижу в коде вызов зерна для рандома, что навевает то что у вас всегда одинаковая последовательность значений

Comment: Я пытался найти решение ошибки в интернете, но не нашел. Либо увидел ответ, но не понял, что это то, что я ищу, в силу того, что раньше никогда не приходилось работать с БД. Обычно, если нужно решить какую-то задачу, я либо пишу код сам, либо нахожу похожий, а потом редактирую его под свою задачу и все работает, а тут так не получилось, видимо из-за нехватки знаний в теме БД. Спасибо за помощь!